# Dúvida em modelagem de tabela auto-relacional

Tags: sql-server, modelagem, tabela-banco-de-dados, sql-server-express

Preciso fazer um sistema onde a regra de negócio é a seguinte:

- Uma carta deve duelar contra outra carta
- O mesmo duelo entre duas cartas iguais podem acontecer mais de uma vez
- Cada carta deve conter apenas duas imagens referente a ela mesma, uma para parte da frente e outra para parte de trás
- O sistema deve exibir um rank, contabilizando quantas partidas todas as cartas ganharam e perderam.

Pensando em resolver o problema eu cheguei a conclusão de criar uma tabela carta que é auto-relacional, como no diagrama abaixo:

[![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][1]][1]

Onde `fk_carta_oponente` faz referência ao `id_carta` e guarda o ID da carta oponente.

Como cada carta precisa ter duas imagens, se eu criasse os campos para essas imagens dentro da tabela acima, toda vez que houvesse um novo duelo eu teria que adicionar novamente os mesmo valores das imagens nos campos.Para resolver isso eu criei outra tabela assim:

[![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][2]][2]

Porém o campo `nome` que está na tabela `carta` iria ficar se repetindo da mesma forma.Em qual tabela eu iria ter que colocar esse campo `nome` para que ele não ficasse se repetindo toda vez que houvesse um novo duelo entre as cartas ? Ou se eu estou indo pelo caminho errado, qual seria outra melhor maneira de resolver esse problema ?

Answer (score 1):

Trazendo para uma abstração deferente, que na minha cabeça ficaria mais organizado.

- Carta deveria guardar os dados de carta.

cartas(id, nome, img_frente, img_costa)

- Duelo faria menção ao relacionamento que você propôs.

duelo(id, id_opnente_1, id_openente_2, id_vencedor)

- O Ranking seria montado com algo do tipo.

Vire de Vitórias:

```
SELECT
   C.id,
   COUNT(D.id_vencedor) AS Vitorias 
FROM duelos D
INNER JOIN cartas C 
ON C.id = id_vencedor
GROUP BY
  C.id
```

View para as derrotas:

```
SELECT
   C.id,
   COUNT(C.id) AS Derrotas 
FROM duelos D
INNER JOIN cartas C 
ON C.id IN (id_openente_1, id_openente_2) 
AND C.id != id_vencedor 
GROUP BY 
  C.id
```

- Depois junte as duas views r calcule o saldo da carta com Vitorias - Derrotas.

Acho que seria algo mais ou menos assim na minha opnião.

Comment: Eu também pensei nessa possibilidade,mas as tabelas cartas e duelo fariam um relacionamento N x N, e nós sabemos que nesse tipo de relacionamento deve-se criar uma tabela auxiliar, nesse caso a tabela `duelo` iria sair e então surgir mais duas tabelas, agora eu lhe pergunto, quais dados seriam guardados na tabela auxiliar e na outra tabela ?

Comment: Na verdade não são duas tabela. São duas visões que apenas consolidam separadamente, vitorias e derrotas, e uma terceira visão que não citei lá, que representaria o ranking. Mas como escopo de modelagem, seriam mesmo cartas e duelos.

Comment: Eu editei a publicação, explicando melhor o que eu quis dizer,Da uma olhada la por favor.

Comment: Eu vi lá que você criou uma abordagem parecida com a que eu falei, partindo de lá, não já mais o que modelar a nível de dados, não há mais tabelas nativas de massa de dados a serem criadas, tá tudo certinho. Só o que tem a fazer é montar a visualizações de precisa, de Vitorias Derrotas e Rankink, ou tudo junto mostrando o saldo das cartas.

Comment: Mas o relacionamento vai ficar N x N, seria errado prosseguir assim certo ?

Comment: Na minha opinião não, uma carta/delegação pode duelar varias vezes com outras cartas/delegações, daí é natural que se o relacionamento pode se repetir, isso seja N. Um relacionamento N x N não é errado se for necessário.